# how to contain a div tag inside a section tag in html

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making a full section page website like [this](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage). Each page is its own `<section>` tag. Currently my page has 4 sections (presented with different background colors).

My first section has a container div and inside two new divs (one for an image and the other for a description). Now when the window is minimized, the contents of the description spills over and goes over to the second page instead of being contained in the first page. To illustrate:
[image]

Please let me know what changes to make. I've been working on this issue for a long time and I have yet to find a resource or solution that works for my code..

My HTML code:

```
<!-- FIRST PAGE -->
<section>
  <div class="content" id="about">
    <!-- Picture -->
    <div id="aboutImage">
      <img src="img/about.jpeg">
    </div>

    <!-- Description -->
    <div id = "aboutInfo">

      <h2>Lorem Ipsum.</h2>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> 
        Suspendisse malesuada lacus commodo enim varius, <br> non gravida ipsum faucibus. 
        Vivamus pretium pulvinar <br> elementum. In vehicula ut elit vitae dapibus. 
        Cras ipsum <br> neque, finibus id mattis vehicula, rhoncus in mauris. 
        In <br> hendrerit vitae velit vel consequat. Duis eleifend dui vel <br> tempor 
        maximus. Aliquam rutrum id dolor vel ullamcorper. <br> Nunc cursus sapien 
        a ex porta dictum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- SECOND PAGE-->
<section id="skills"></section>
```

My CSS:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
 html, body {width: 100%;}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

html, body {
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
}

section{
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.content{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* ABOUT */
#about {
  border-bottom: #F1C40F 5px solid;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
 }

#aboutImage {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

#aboutInfo {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;

  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

#aboutInfo p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* SECOND PAGE*/
#skills {
   background-color: #E3E7D3;
}

/* RESPONSIVE DESIGN */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  #about {
    flex-direction: column; /* added */
  } 
}
```

Please please let me know how to fix this. I've been having so much trouble.

Comment: Play around with "overflow" - you're probably showing it, when you want to clip it, or use a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to `CSS` of `#aboutInfo` `div`. What this will do is that whenever there's overflow of content, instead of going to the next page, that div will scroll the content.

Test it here [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGPdEb)

Additionally, i also added `margin-bottom: 20px;` to `CSS` of `#aboutInfo` `div` just so you can see that this div doesn't overflows to next page anymore.

Comment: thank! wow such an easy fix! I was wondering is there any other way to do this? I've seen other websites and instead of adding a scroll bar, the page that its on expands to fit the content.